# Android Support Toolbar colorControlNormal color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I would like to set my spinner drop down color to white, whilst keeping the other elements in my theme the default color. Here is the situation:

[image: Toolbar and spinner]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme.Base"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And the style is:

```
<!-- My base app theme -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_tint</item>

    <!-- <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item> -->

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_primary</item>
</style>

<!-- My Toolbar theme -->
<style name="ToolbarTheme.Base" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

If I was to put `<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>` in the App theme (commented out above) then the spinner drop down will do to white BUT the checkbox will also turn white. So how can I get the spinner ONLY to go white?

Comment: What happens when you remove `colorControlNormal` from `ToolbarTheme.Base` entirely?

Comment: No difference, the spinner stays grey.

Comment: I had the same problem, it seems to work on some devices and not others http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739022/change-spinner-style-in-toolbar

Answer (score 21):

Finally, I have found a solution on how to change arrow color of `Spinner` to white.

1) In `styles.xml`, add the following style:

```
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ff33b5e5</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyTheme.HeaderBar.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

2) In the layout, where you use the `Spinner` (in your case with `Toolbar`), add the style to your spinner:

```
<Spinner
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/my_spinner"
         style="@style/Widget.MyTheme.HeaderBar.Spinner"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try as soon as I can.

Comment: I have tried the same but I am not able to see any change on my spinner arrow ,,It remain same white color.. I want to change it to Black color. do you think  there is any other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: OKay, I've looked through a lot of tutorials and stackoverflow answers, this is definitely the one I think that addresses this problem the best.

Answer (score 18):

Just stumbled across this questions. Even though it has been asked some time ago I just wanted to leave an answer that should work:

**Toolbar *.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    <!-- leave the theme stuff out of here -->
    style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

**Styles / Themes**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- your other attributes -->
    <!-- following is used to tint the checkbox - purple for demo purpose -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#2196F3</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:minHeight">?actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">?colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/MyToolbarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
    <!-- Used to tint the back arrow, menu and spinner arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

**Result**

[image: solution with different colors for spinner and checkbox]

*Note: I made the checkbox purple for demo purpose*

Comment: This didn't work for me, although the @yuriy-yunikov answer, with setting the colors for Spinner through the `android:theme` works like a charm.

Comment: Please keep in mind, that it's crucial to set the style on the `Spinner` itself with `style` attribute, because setting it through application theme doesn't seem to propagate the `theme` attribute for `Spinner`.

Comment: @DamianWalczak Post is a little bit old and I have to check this. But I think my approach should still work. Furthermore since Appcompat v22 I think you can set `android:theme` for every view element - so the `style` stuff is obsolete as well.