# Change spinner style in toolbar

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to put a spinner in my `Toolbar` like the old ActionBar style navigation and my theme is this

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_primary</item>
</style>
```

but my spinner is black while all other icons and overflow menus are white so it looks bad

[image]

I tried changing the style of the spinner using this

```
<style name="ToolbarSpinnerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/TextAppearanceSpinnerItem</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearanceSpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

this is how my Toolbar is styled

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
           app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
           app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

           <Spinner
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/modes"
               android:minWidth="150dp"
               android:gravity="bottom"
               style="@style/ToolbarSpinnerTheme"/>

       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


final Spinner mode = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.modes);

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.action_bar_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mode.setAdapter(mSpinner);
```

but it always stays black. How can I change the spinner arrow and text to white while still keeping the same theme for the dropdown style as you would get with the `Light` theme?

**Update 4.4 arrow fix:**

The only way I got the arrow to turn white is to add the spinner programatically and not in xml so it looks something like this

```
final ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(),
        R.array.main_navigation_list, R.layout.spinner_text);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
mNavigationTags = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_navigation_list);


mNavigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
mNavigationSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

mNavigationSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
mToolbar.addView(mNavigationSpinner)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for creating the adapter and spinner?

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo I dont see how that will help but its there

Comment: Can you also post the spinner xml?

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo edited again

Comment: see this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852108/how-do-you-set-the-title-color-for-the-new-toolbar

Comment: I posted my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31053663/4255576 Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create the arrayadapter you should do getApplicationContext instead of this:

```
SpinnerAdapter mSpinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array. action_bar_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Make a new layout file:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:id="@android:id/text1"
                 style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
                 android:singleLine="true"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
                 android:ellipsize="marquee"
                 android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

Then change your code to this:

```
ArrayAdapter mAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array. action_bar_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
        mode.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

---

Have you tried putting the spinner in the xml file like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And also disable the title like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer is from Chris Banes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26511653/2767703

Comment: this has nothing to do with my question, I want to know how to change the style of my spinner

Comment: @tyczj The style can be tinted wrong because there is no inflation. By putting the Spinner inside your xml it might be inflated properly and give the white text you want

Comment: I have the spinner in my toolbar so again this is not the issue at hand

Comment: @tyczj I changed my answer, have a look. I don't know what the default theming doesn't work, but this should be the style for spinners

Comment: @tyczj I'm trying it out in my own project, that's what's taking me so long

Comment: no problem, basically I want to get the style like you will with the dark theme but with the light popup style

Comment: @tyczj no style needed so far, getApplicationContext gives the white spinner. Only problem is that dropdown is also white textcolor, trying to fix this

Comment: that and the arrow is still black, but interesting that the context made a difference

Comment: @tyczj arrow should be white, I created new project and did the same as your code above. My arrow is white

Comment: hmm the arrow is black for me

Comment: @tyczj I edited my code, this gives you black letters. I don't know why the arrow is black for you. Probably because of the style you gave it (you can delete that style). Hope this solves your issue

Comment: yeah its weird, I took out all my themes but I still get the black arrow, other than that it looks good

Comment: @tyczj if you update your code I'll have a look. Try cleaning the project though, it could help

Comment: @KenivvanMierlo I ran it on my nexus 7 with 5.0 and it shows fine except now the popup is black along with the text lol. I might just have to edit that layout and specify the background color

Comment: @tyczj Oh that's weird. But now you know how ;)

Comment: @tyczj Which layout you edited with background color?

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo I found a solution to the arrow problem, you cannot add the spinner in xml and must do it programatically with the context of the actionbar

Comment: @tyczj Glad you solved it! I'll remember that in case I need it

Answer (score 21):

I do it like the following:

[image]

navigation_toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

MainActivity.java

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.pass_type, R.layout.layout_drop_title);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.layout_drop_list);

 Spinner mNavigationSpinner = new Spinner(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
 mNavigationSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
 getToolbar().addView(mNavigationSpinner);
```

You will find I used custom spinner item layout, `layout_drop_title` and `layout_drop_list`

layout_drop_title.xml

```
 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

layout_drop_list.xml

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:background="@color/nliveo_blue_colorPrimary"
android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

Comment: thanks for you edit ,i am not familiar with edit box for stackoverflow and i will grope

Comment: great, `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` along with `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"` were a key for arrow

Answer (score 9):

Kevin is in the right direction but the real answer is not to use the application context but the already themed context of the action bar itself. This is actually mentioned in the [documenation](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) but it doesn't get that much emphasis all along:

> When inflating anything to be displayed on the action bar (such as a
>   SpinnerAdapter for list navigation in the toolbar), make sure you use
>   the action bar’s themed context, retrieved via
>   getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext().

Comment: I just tried using the `ThemeContext` but that didnt change the color of the arrow still