# Changing the hamburger icon color in navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml

Hamburger icon color of navigation drawer is not changing. Its black by default. I want to change it to @color/gold. its working for API below 21. Please help me.

here is the style i am using.

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gold</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/gold</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/gold</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/gold</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/gold</item>

</style>
```

Answer thanks to Iron man

changed the entire theme

```
  <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/booking</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/booking</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/booking</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/booking</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/booking</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/booking</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the color of the ActionBar hamburger icon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30760807/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-actionbar-hamburger-icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give tint color of your icon below way

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu, null);
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.GOLD);
actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
```

Comment: can i change it via theme

Comment: @Sreepulari you can do it via Theme also but you have to change the Theme from `NoActionBar` to some ActionBar Theme and apply it.

Comment: @Sreepulari glad to know that.

Answer (score 4):

Create style in your styles.xml and put the following code

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

And then add the theme like so:

```
< item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

Comment: I have been searching every where and this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, programmatically you just need to add below line of code...

```
actionBarDrawerToggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable()
                     .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

**write this code into your values/style**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
<item name="spinBars">true</item>
<item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```