# Cannot alter Toolbar Text and Icon Colors

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles

I've been struggling with this all day - I've been on Stack Overflow for hours trying various solutions to no avail.

The application I'm building uses the light material theme, yet the text on the toolbar refuses to change from anything but black. The toolbar itself colors perfectly.

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:color">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">@dimen/toolbar_elevation</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

in the activity layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="@string/app_name" />
```

Hoping someone can help solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `Toolbar`:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Or perhaps, Adding this:

`ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` instead of `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark` you forgot to add `ActionBar` at the end i guess.

And of course, If you have `AppBarLayout`, Try to add this line in your `AppBarLayout` too:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

Texts will be white.

---

**Otherwise, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26852454/4409113) will help:**

> Option 1) The quick and easy way (Toolbar only)
>
> > Since `appcompat-v7-r23` you can use the following attributes directly
> >     on your `Toolbar` or its style:

```
app:titleTextColor="@color/primary_text"
app:subtitleTextColor="@color/secondary_text"
```