# Dynamically Adding and Removing Spinner from Toolbar in a Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have referenced this post: [Change spinner style in toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739022/change-spinner-style-in-toolbar) to enable a spinner in the new toolbar. My question is if I want to add or remove this spinner based on when different fragments are displayed, how can I remove this if it is being inflated in the toolbar xml?

With the actionbar, I could add or remove menu items, can I do the same with the id of the spinner from the xml? Right now, the spinner comes up blank when it is in a fragment without me populating it with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using `View.setVisibility(int)` to hide a `Spinner` in my `Toolbar` based on the current `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    switch (getCurrentFragment()) {
          case FRAGMENT_WITH_SPINNER:
              mSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              break;
          case FRAGMENT_WITHOUT_SPINNER:
              mSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              break;
     }
        return true;
}
```

I do this in onCreateOptionsMenu() so it is refreshed when some component call

```
mActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Hey, this worked great! Thank you. I have not run into any problems with a few runs of it. Will continue testing. I will accept in 3 minutes.