# Appcompat Toolbar doesn't give styles to spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, android-appcompat

I need all the icons and text in the toolbar to be light, and the overflow menu, the spinner, and the drawer (not shown in image) to all have a light backgrounds and dark text. (Using the android themes)

Why is only the overflow doing it how I'd like, but the drawer (not shown) and the spinner staying dark?

Any ideas help! (even though I feel I've tried everything)

Must be IDENTICAL to [this](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7SXp4WFFUZDZwSE0/components_menus_usage1.png)

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/teal700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    ...
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

[image: Why is it doing this?]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change spinner style in toolbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739022/change-spinner-style-in-toolbar)

Comment: Did you ever get the arrow to be white?

Comment: I did, however its not in the answer. What you have to do it add the spinner programatically and not in xml. see `user3461233`s answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755878/how-can-i-fix-the-spinner-style-for-android-4-x-placed-on-top-of-the-toolbar

Comment: @tyczj Thank you, that's what I need to keep moving forward.