# Tint CheckBox and Toolbar stuff separately

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm currently using the usually amazing `appcompat-v7` library in my application and I'm trying to tint my `CheckBoxes` without changing the Icon-Colors in the `Toolbar` (like the back arrow or those three dots).

Following how it looks currently - as you can see not only the CheckBox is tinted pink, the back-arrow / three-dots are also tinted pink.

[image: picture showing issue]

My code:

**Layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="My CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Application-Theme**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFC107</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFA000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFF</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#E91E63</item>
</style>
```

#### Question

What do I need to change so that the Checkbox gets pink and the Toolbar-stuff keeps being white?

Side-Note:
I guess the main problem is that I simply can't find a page where every single appcompat attribute is described. It's basically just all-out trial and error since the names of those attributes are no clear indication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135499/android-checkbox-style check this answer

Comment: @Arlind I just looked at it but unfortunately it doesn't work. The custom `checkboxStyle` works for the `textColor` but not for the color of the CheckBox itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically facing the same issue as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537371/android-support-toolbar-colorcontrolnormal-color/29536902#29536902) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29464078/change-toolbar-background-color-programmatically-does-not-change-toolbar-title-b/29533038#29533038) question.
So the only thing you need to do is to create a `Style` for your `Toolbar` which uses an other theme as the `Activity`.

**Toolbar style / theme example**

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle">
    <!-- potential other attributes -->
    <item name="theme">@style/MyToolbarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
    <!-- Used to tint the back arrow, menu and spinner arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
</style>
```

Add this Style to your Toolbar and your issue should be fixed (it is important not to use the theme directly):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/MyToolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp" />
```