# Tint CheckBox and Toolbar with different colors in nested preference activity

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-theme, preferenceactivity

When I first start looking over this question I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502571/tint-checkbox-and-toolbar-stuff-separately) question, but the answer didn't work for me. I am working on a **KitKat** phone, but from what I read, this can be done on a pre-lollipop versions using the `AppCompat` library. I am using [this](https://github.com/davcpas1234/MaterialSettings) GitHub repo, and more specificaly [this](https://github.com/davcpas1234/MaterialSettings/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/verscreative/materialsettings/SettingsExampleActivity.java) code sample to create nested preference screen.

Here is my `AppTheme.SettingsTheme` for the `SettingActivity` in the code sample:

```
<style name="AppTheme.SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
</style>
```

This line:  `<item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>` changes the `Toolbar` from having a **white** text and **black** back arrow, to having both the text and back arrow appear **white** (which is good).

The issue is that I have a `CheckBoxPreference` which is tinted with this line also, so when it in not check, I can barely see it (box color is **white**).

[image]

[image]

I tried creating a special theme just for the toolbar (again from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502571/tint-checkbox-and-toolbar-stuff-separately) answer) and doing the `<item name="colorControlNormal">COLOR</item>`, but its just doesn't affect to toolbar.

I also tried to tint the `CheckBoxPreference` alone, but it seems that in involves creating a custom layout for it, and this brings a lot more work.

Here is my toolbar layout, currently with no specific theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.settingsActivity.SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
        app:navigationIcon="?homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:title="@string/activity_settings_title"
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Can anybody explain how to tint the `CheckBoxPreference` and `Toolbar` seperatly? I don't care which one of them I tint using the `ActivityTheme` and which one I tint on its custom `theme`. The answers I found didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the theme for your `Toolbar` specifically, instead of for your entire `Activity`. This is what the [`ThemeOverlay`](https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35#.yauhocu3v) styles are meant for (they use the `colorControlNormal` attribute when necessary). You can also define a separate "popup" theme if you would like light-themed pop-ups from your dark `Toolbar`:

```
<style name="SettingsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SettingsTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<style name="SettingsTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Then you can apply these styles in your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.settingsActivity.SettingsActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
        app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"
        app:navigationIcon="?homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:title="@string/activity_settings_title"
        app:popupTheme="@style/SettingsTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you please provide an example on how exactly to theme only the toolbar to have both the text and the back arrow colors white, while activity theme is not affected? I tried copying the code you provided, it made my toolbar's text and back arrow black

Comment: @OfekAgmon This is the code I use in my build. The `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` style should make the text and icons white in your `AppBarLayout` and `Toolbar`. Are you positive you applied the theme correctly?

Comment: yes, I copied your exactly the way it is..  if the ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar should make the toolbar and icons white, what is the ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light for? anyway, its still black in my app..

Comment: @OfekAgmon Any `ThemeOverlay` is used to override the current theme with another. I use `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light` to override the `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` for any pop-ups that the `Toolbar` produces (such as the overflow menu).

Comment: @OfekAgmon This is actually the default theme that Android Studio provides for a new project. If you start a brand new project, with a new `Activity`, Android Studio will generate the same theme for you. Along with an `Activity` that uses the `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` for the `AppBarLayout` theme.

Comment: So, apparently the Github repo for the nested settings screen caused the issues. I switched to  ferrannp/material-preferences https://github.com/ferrannp/material-preferences and didn't need to set any teme for the toolbar. its really is the default theme