# Toolbar item color (3 dots)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, nativescript, android-theme, angular2-nativescript

I know that when I set "colorControlNormal" color change in most of ui elements, but I need change only items in toolbar.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/ToolBar</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/PrimaryDarkGreen</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryGreen</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/AccentGreen</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/PrimaryWhite</item>        
</style>

<style name="ToolBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/PrimaryGreen</item>
</style>
```

**Update**
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPrq8.png)

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem here ? You can also assign a value to **colorControlNormal** in your Toolbar theme. Check this link.

[Android Support Toolbar colorControlNormal color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537371/android-support-toolbar-colorcontrolnormal-color)

Answer (score 1):

Check this this. This will change overflow button(3 dots).

```
public  PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilterWhite= new PorterDuffColorFilter( getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
final String overflowDescription = getString(R.string.abc_action_menu_overflow_description);
final ViewGroup decorView = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();
final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = decorView.getViewTreeObserver();


        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                final ArrayList<View> outViews = new ArrayList<View>();
                decorView.findViewsWithText(outViews, overflowDescription,
                        View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
                if (outViews.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }
                AppCompatImageView overflow=(AppCompatImageView) outViews.get(0);
                overflow.setColorFilter(colorFilterWhite);
                if(viewTreeObserver.isAlive())
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                else
                    decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
```

**OR**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Make changes either in Java file or in the XML .

Comment: I need change items in toolbar, not background.

Comment: question was about item in toolbar but not background